# SQL Query count rows where multiple column-values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, pivot

So this is a how my MySQL table looks like (I have many thousands of rows):

```
| ID |         date        |   Color |   IUSERQ | 
|  1 | 2020-09-25 18:55:54 |    RED  |    GGW3  |
|  2 | 2020-09-25 18:24:12 |    RED  |    FFQ3  |
|  3 | 2020-09-24 17:32:52 |    RED  |    GWW3  |
|  4 | 2020-09-23 17:42:37 |   BLUE  |    JJN6  |
|  5 | 2020-09-23 17:33:55 |   BLUE  |    VVV5  |
|  6 | 2020-09-23 18:53:57 |    RED  |    FFQ3  |
|  7 | 2020-09-22 18:15:11 |   BLUE  |    FFQ3  |
```

Now to count all of the rows and group them in weeks, I do this:

```
if($stmt = $link->query("SELECT WEEK(date),COUNT(*) FROM sales WHERE color='RED' AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()) GROUP BY WEEK(date) order by MONTH(date) ASC")){

$php_data_array = Array(); // create PHP array
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_row()) {
   $php_data_array[] = $row; // Adding to array
   }
}else{
echo $link->error;
}

echo json_encode($php_data_array);
```

On the `echo json_encode($php_data_array);`, it gives the this current output: `[["36","154"],["37","247"],["38","275"]]`. So the first string in the array (36, 37, 38) is the week number, and the second one the number of rows where color is RED. Now, I also want to add where color is BLUE in the same array, so the expected value should be something like: `[["36","154","166"],["37","247","265"],["38","275","298"]]`.

What approach should I use to do this?

Comment: Why not simply GROUP BY colour?

Comment: ...although I'm struggling to see how the data set matches up with the result set

Comment: @Strawberry How are you struggling? I basically copy/pasted from my project.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

Just add another column:

```
SELECT WEEK(date) as week, SUM(color = 'RED') as red, SUM(color = 'BLUE') as blue
FROM sales
WHERE color IN ('RED', 'BLUE') AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW())
GROUP BY WEEK(date)
ORDER BY WEEK(date) ASC;
```

Note the changes to the query:

- The `SUM()` does conditional aggregation for each color.
- The columns are given names, which can be used to reference them in the application.
- The `ORDER BY` is by the column being aggregated.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select week(date) week_date, sum(color = 'RED') cnt_red, sum(color = 'BLUE') cnt_blue
from sales 
where color in ('RED', 'BLUE') and date >= date_format(current_date, '%Y-%m-01')
group by week(date) 
order by week_date
```

Note that this uses direct filtering on the `date` column, without applying functions on the filtered column. This is more efficient that `year(date) = year(now())`, especially if you have an index on that column.

I also changed the `order by` clause: obviously, you want to order by week rather than month (in most databases, that's a compilation error, because the month does not belong to the `group by` clause).

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic query as another option :

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
             DISTINCT
             CONCAT(
                    'SUM( color =''', color, ''' ) AS ',color
                    )
       )
  INTO @sql
  FROM sales s;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT WEEK(date) AS WEEK,',@sql,
                   ' FROM sales
                    WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()) 
                    GROUP BY WEEK
                    ORDER BY WEEK');
```

and then call from php code block such as :

```
if($stmt = $link->query( @sql )){ ....
$php_data_array = Array(); // create PHP array
....
```

This way, no need to add each color name to be grouped individually, the query pivots all color column values whichever exist within the table. New colors might be added or existing ones might be deleted without constructing new querie.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f036ee9631f55392df608ce4c6c5366a)</kbd> *(in order to show result of the query)*

Comment: I just don't see what benefit this affords versus handling all of the display logic in the application code

Comment: well, the data might differ, some new color name may be presented as new records inserted. I think no need to individually write each of them in order to pivot. I don't know whether some other pivoting techniques exist in application side, since I don't know php @Strawberry .

Comment: Plainly, you know php well enough!! :-)